# What's the difference between useState and useImmer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, immer.js

I have seen some React applications utilize [`useImmer`](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) as a hook instead of `useState`. I am not understanding what `useImmer` offers that `useState` does not.

What is an advantage of using `useImmer` over using the official `useState`?

Comment: Try this, I think it explains the advantages very well: https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-with-immer/ (But be aware it can be an overkill depending on the usage. What I mean is that useState does the trick for most of the situations.

Answer (score 35):

In the nutshell, immer facilitates the way you mutate nested/complex data structures. Have a look at these 2 ways:

consider below object:

```
const [product, updateProduct] = useState({
    name: "Product 1",
    SKU: "SKU-001",
    availability: 30,
    stock: [
      {
        id: 1, 
        store: "Store 1",
        quantity: 10
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        store: "Store 2",
        quantity: 20
      }
    ]
  });
```

In order to manipulate this, you should pass the whole object and override the property you would like to update/change:

```
updateProduct({ ...product, name: "Product 1 - Updated" })
```

However, if you use "useImmer" you can send the only part you would like to change and immer itself will take care of the rest under the hood.

```
  const [product, updateProduct] = useImmer({
    name: "Product 1",
    SKU: "SKU-001",
    availability: 30,
    stock: [
      {
        id: 1, 
        store: "Store 1",
        quantity: 10
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        store: "Store 2",
        quantity: 20
      }
    ]
  });
```

So to update:

```
updateProduct((draft) => { 
   draft.name = "Product Updated" };
})
```

It does make more sense when you are manipulating complex structure, let say if you want to change the second object in the "Stock" array, then you can use:

```
updateProduct((draft) => {
    draft.stock[1].quantity = 30;
})
```

Comment: Using the immer version of `updateProduct`, how would you go about updating the value for `draft.name` if it was previously null or undefined? Accessing it that way would throw an error no?

Comment: @ksingh If draft is null, we can return new object. Either we can modify the draft or return new object. It works.